# Set custom message for DeleteWithConfirmButton react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

How can I send my message to DeleteWithConfirmButton not globally, but only to one?

I can change the message globally:

```
const messages = {
  en: {
    ra: {
      message: {
        delete_contents: 'HELLO?'
      }
    }
  }
};

const i18nProvider = locale => messages[locale];

 <Admin
    i18nProvider={i18nProvider}
```

delete_content: 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?', - default message

```
DeleteWithConfirmButton.propTypes = {
basePath: PropTypes.string,
classes: PropTypes.object,
className: PropTypes.string,
crudDelete: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
label: PropTypes.string,
record: PropTypes.object,
redirect: PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.bool,
    PropTypes.func,
]),
resource: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
translate: PropTypes.func,
icon: PropTypes.element,
};
```

Comment: What is crudDelete? Is that part of the React-Admin framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current version of React-admin, the DeleteButton / BulkDeleteButton components have the confirmTitle / confirmContent properties, to set a custom header and dialog content:

```
DeleteWithConfirmButton.propTypes = {
    basePath: PropTypes.string,
    classes: PropTypes.object,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    
    confirmTitle: PropTypes.string,       
    confirmContent: PropTypes.string,
    
    label: PropTypes.string,
    record: PropTypes.any,
    redirect: PropTypes.oneOfType([
        PropTypes.string,
        PropTypes.bool,
        PropTypes.func,
    ]),
    resource: PropTypes.string,
    icon: PropTypes.element,
};
```